# Launching celery tasks in cherrypy

Tags: python, celery, cherrypy

i am building restful interface using cherrypy and i need to launch some celery tasks 
But it seems doesn't work and i have no idea why?

Myaybe someone was faced with such.

So, i have celeryconfig.py

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "sqlite:///celerydb.sqlite" 
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", ) 
CELERY_RESULT_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"echo": True} 
BROKER_TRANSPORT = "sqlalchemy" 
BROKER_HOST = "sqlite:///celerydb.sqlite"
```

And tasks.py

```
from celery.task import task

@task
def create_agent(agent_id):
    print ("do something")
```

I am launching celeryd

```
celeryd -l INFO
```

Also i have a request handler (CherryPy)

```
class Resource(object):
    def POST(self):
        create_agent.delay(1)
```

I can call create_agent.delay(1) task from the python console and celery worker gets the task and work
But when create_agent.delay(1) is called in cherrypy (by touching appropriate url)
celery worker does not get the task at all.

And more. I use python3.2

Answer (score 4):

If you run celeryd in debug mode (`celeryd -l debug`), you should get a hint:

```
[2012-02-15 09:34:35,484: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'default.create_agent'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.
```

(For future reference, run celeryd in `debug` mode when you have issues like this; `info` isn't going to tell you much.)

That bit.ly url points to this:
http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports

You should be able to resolve this error by changing your decorator to this:
`@task(name='tasks.create_agent')`

I'm running python 2.7 and celery 2.3.1. I was able to reproduce your issue and the fix above worked for me.

I hope that helps.

Comment: It was a very stuppid situation. I have been launching `celeryd -l` info command  being indirectory  which does not contain celeryconfig.py file. I just did `cd ./src`  and `celeryd -l info` and it worked like a charm   Thanks you for help.